# Having trouble with deck of cards

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods, compiler-errors

I am having trouble with this part of the code. I keep getting a null pointer exception when calling the method. Im not sure whats wrong with it.

```
class Deck{

public Card[] myCards = new Card[52];

void refreshDeck(){
    int cardValue = 1;
    char cardSuit = 'c';     

    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
        myCards[i].setValue(cardValue);
        myCards[i].setSuit(cardSuit);

        if (cardValue == 13){
            cardValue = 0;
            switch(cardSuit){
                case 'c':
                    cardSuit = 's';
                    break;
                case 's':
                    cardSuit = 'd';
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    cardSuit = 'h';
                    break;
            }
        }
        cardValue++;
    }
}
```

I really cant find the error. and this works on c++.

Comment: Yea like the answer below, you have initialized the array of cards, but you are not creating a new Card object for each position in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initialize each card in the array. Try that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
    myCards[i] = new Card();//a constructor
    myCards[i].setValue(cardValue);
    myCards[i].setSuit(cardSuit);
    //...
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew I had to initialize something just didnt know what.

Comment: You are welcome. If you are ok with my answer please mark your question as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialised each card in your array, add

```
myCards[i] = new Card();
```

To the start of your for loop

Answer (score 0):

You've build an array of 52 references to `Card` objects, but the objects haven't been created yet. The array is then an array of 52 null references. You need to build each one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
    myCards[i] = new Card();
    ...
```

It would be much better to add an adequate constructor to `Card` to be able to write :

```
    myCards[i] = new Card(cardValue,cardSuit);
```